# uninitialized constant Syck::DefaultResolver

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, yaml, ruby-1.9.1

I'm a fairly new dev to ruby and especially rails, but I do have some perl and php experience. Anyway, I'm trying to get `rails` version 3 configured on Ubuntu 10.10 using the latest ruby package: `v1.9.2-p136`. It isn't going too well, though better than `p0`: at least they included the `yaml.rb` and friends, so that I'm not spending my time cobbling them together. However, I'm still having a problem with the YAML package, which manifests itself whenever I try to install or configure *any* gem or package. I installed rails through `synaptic` already; this was just for showcasing the problem.

```
gem i rails
ERROR:  Loading command: install (NameError)
uninitialized constant Syck::DefaultResolver
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::InstallCommand
```

This actually showed up when I tried to install `redmine` with `synaptic`: it now says every synaptic installation ends in failure, all because of:

```
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Syck::DefaultResolver
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2482:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:82:in `<module:Syck>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/syck.rb:80:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/yaml/syck.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/vendor_gem_source_index.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/config/boot.rb:45:in `load_initializer'
/usr/share/redmine/config/boot.rb:38:in `run'
/usr/share/redmine/config/boot.rb:11:in `boot!'
/usr/share/redmine/config/boot.rb:110:in `<top (required)>'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
/usr/share/redmine/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2373:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2007:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2058:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:2006:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake.rb:1991:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:31:in `<main>'
dpkg: error processing redmine (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

Comment: Could you show us how you installed this Ruby? It looks like it's broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a guide on installing this version of Ruby: http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you. It should get you up and running in no time.